# How to create Windows Service in C/C++?

Tags: c++, c, windows-services

I want to create Windows Service (application running in background) using C/C++ language. How can I do this, can you give me a tutorial ?

Comment: There's not C/C++ language. There are two languages, C and C++, which just happen to have an above-average degree of interoperability.

Comment: @MSalters I know that are different languages. I mean that I will do that in C **or** C++ . My solution is designed for that both langs.

Comment: It compiles in VC++, but a C++ programmer would use a class to encapsulate the service. That's just one example of the different idioms with C++. In fact, a C++ programmer would probably separate generic implementation in a base `Service` class and put specifics in a derived class.

Comment: @MSalters that works propely, I know that there are other possibilities, but I am using it as the best.

Answer (score 1):

Another platform independent way is to use [boost::application](https://github.com/retf/Boost.Application)

Example how to use can be found [here](https://github.com/retf/Boost.Application/blob/master/example/simple_server_application.cpp).