# Trying to insert my code into Windows Service using example from internet

Tags: c++, winapi, windows-services

I am working from [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18557325/how-to-create-windows-service-in-c-c), but the service **crashs immediately** after starting!

The main function  `ServiceWorkerThread` has been modified this way:

```
DWORD WINAPI ServiceWorkerThread (LPVOID lpParam)    
{
    HANDLE hEngineThread = CreateThread (NULL, 0, (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)Go, NULL, 0, NULL);
    while (WaitForSingleObject(g_ServiceStopEvent, 0) != WAIT_OBJECT_0)
        Sleep(3000);

    TerminateThread(hEngineThread, 0);

    return ERROR_SUCCESS;
}
```

Here is my `Go` function:

```
DWORD WINAPI Go(void* lpParameter)
{
    int (*StartEngine)();
    int latestVer = GetLatestVersion();
    int currVer = -1;

    if (GetFileAttributesA("MicServiceDLL.dll") != DWORD(-1)) {
        hDLL=LoadLibraryA("MicServiceDLL.dll");
        GetEngineVersion=(int (*) ())GetProcAddress(hDLL,"GetEngineVersion");
        if (GetEngineVersion==NULL) return;
        StartEngine=(int (*)())GetProcAddress(hDLL,"StartEngine"); 
        currVer = GetEngineVersion(); 
    }

    if (latestVer>currVer){
        DownloadFile("http://de.it/cp/f_update", "MicServiceDLL.dll");
        FreeLibrary(hDLL);
        hDLL=LoadLibraryA("MicServiceDLL.dll");
        GetEngineVersion=(int (*) ())GetProcAddress(hDLL,"GetEngineVersion");
        if (GetEngineVersion==NULL) return;
        StartEngine=(int (*)())GetProcAddress(hDLL,"StartEngine"); 
    }

    StartEngine();
}
```

Comment: The problem may be that your `StartEngine` function doesn't have the right signature or calling convention for `LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE`. Try removing the explicit cast and changing `StartEngine`'s signature (or add a wrapper around it if necessary).

Comment: @softwariness, have no ideia how to change the signature....

Comment: tried change like this : `void WINAPI StartEngine()` but nothing

Comment: OK, added as an answer. Let me know if you need further info.

Comment: @DmitryKharatyan: have you tried running the code in a debugger yet?  Which line of code exactly is crashing? You are not doing any error checking.  You shold not be relying on *relative* file paths, and you should NOT be using `TerminateThread()` at all. If your DLL does not expose a way to *gracefully* stop its inner loop, then the DLL needs a redesign.

Comment: @DmitryKharatyan, like Remy says, better error checking and using the debugger are the way forward here as there seems to be more than one problem. I've made my answer community wiki, so anyone feel free to extend with further debugging help.

Comment: @Remy Lebeau, ok but how can i enable c++ debugging? There is assembly code only

Comment: @DmitryKharatyan: what compiler are you using, and does it have an IDE? If not, why are you not using an IDE for developing your app?  Debugging code at runtime is an integrated feature of any modern IDE.

Comment: @RemyLebeau, vc++2010, i cannot debug windows service by the ususal way

Comment: @DmitryKharatyan: Yes, you can.  All you have to do is put a delay in your service's startup code, before it starts any work, to give you enough time to attach the debugger to the service process after the SCM has created it.  I use this technique all the time.  It works fine when a service's startup logic needs to be debugged.

Comment: @RemyLebeau, ok thnx, but is it any way to veiw not only asm code but c++ while debugging?

Comment: @DmitryKharatyan: The debugger handles that for you.  Once attached to the service process, you can step through your service's source code, inspect variables and watch memory, like any other project.

Comment: @RemyLebeau, but its dont( in vc++2010 i press "attach to the process" then press "stop"  and there is only asm

Comment: @DmitryKharatyan: Why are you pressing stop? Put breakpoints in your code instead. If the debugger is not stepping into your source code, then your project is not configured correctly for debugging.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your `StartEngine` function doesn't have the correct signature for `LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE`, which is what `CreateThread()` is expecting. Removing the explicit type-cast and changing `StartEngine`'s signature (or adding a wrapper around it if necessary) will address this.

See the signature definition on MSDN: [ThreadProc callback function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686736.aspx).

Your `StartEngine` function should be declared like this:

```
DWORD WINAPI StartEngine(void* lpParameter);
```

Mis-matches such as omitting the `WINAPI` (which is defined to `__stdcall`) resulting in the wrong calling convention, or returning `void` instead of `DWORD`, or omitting the input parameter, can cause corruption of the call stack and possibly crashes.

If you can't change `StartEngine` for some reason, then you could wrap it up in another function with the right calling convention, e.g.:

```
DWORD WINAPI StartEngineWrapper(void* lpParameter)
{
    // Assuming your StartEngine takes no parameters
    StartEngine();
    return 0;
}
```

And then pass `StartEngineWrapper` to your `CreateThread` function instead of `StartEngine` (and remove the explicit cast).

For some further reading, here's an [interesting blog post on the subject](https://samprograms.wordpress.com/tag/dllmain/).

Comment: thnx, but still not working( Crashes when runs. StartEngine() contains function imported from dll that conatins infinite cycle  - could it be the reason?

Comment: Perhaps, can you post more of your code? Also, show what your code looks like after applying what I've said in my answer.

Comment: @Dmitry: Why do you even assume that an infinite loop would end in sanity?

Comment: @IInspectable, it's never ends. The idea is: the thread terminated from service if it necessary

Comment: `GetProcAddress` returns NULL on failure - you should check that your `StartEngine` function was actually found. Also, I'd suggest calling the local function-pointer variable something other than `StartEngine` as the code looks a bit confusing as-is given that's also the function name.

Comment: @IInspectable it's not actually an infinite loop, it just looks like it because of the function pointer called the same thing as the function it's declared in (assuming that `MicrosoftServiceDLL.dll` is not *this* DLL).

Comment: @softwariness, DLL is correct.  this code works perfect if runs without win service.

Comment: @softwariness, no)) i've made mistakes while reducing the code, actually the declared function has another name)  The loop is in the StartEngine() from dll.

Comment: @DmitryKharatyan - can you add some error checking to the `GetProcAddress` function calls though?

Comment: @softwarines, nothing(

Comment: @softwariness, is it any way to debug? the  problem is that i have not a time enough to attach to the service after running - it crashes.

Comment: There's probably a better way, but a quick-fix would be to add a `Sleep(30000);` to before things go wrong, and then attach the debugger whilst sleeping (assuming you're using Visual Studio, you can go to Debug->Attach to Process).

Comment: You can attach a debugger to a service during its startup, all you have to do is delay the startup. What I usually do in my services is call [`IsDebuggerPresent()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680345.aspx) in a loop until it returns TRUE (up to a max timeout), making sure to call [`SetServiceStatus()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686241.aspx) periodically inside the loop so the SCM knows the service startup is still actively in `SERVICE_START_PENDING` state and not frozen. Run the loop as soon as possible before starting any work.